# How to get quantity of a group by recursively summing up quantities of if its undergroups n so on?

Tags: sql

```
    GoupName    Id   UnderGRoupId Quantity
    Computer    66    57          0
    Keyboard    67    66          0
    Monitor     68    66          0
    Mouse       69    66          25
    CPU         70    66          0
    Stationary  71    57          0
    Pencil      72    71          0
    Ruler       73    71          0
    Mechanical  74    67          30
    Membrane    75    67          0
```

This is my view where Quantity of items falling directly under these groups are displayed. I want it to recursively add quantities of groups which directly or  indirectly fall under main group say Computer.

```
        GoupName    Id   UnderGRoupId Quantity
        Computer    66    57          55
        Keyboard    67    66          30
        Monitor     68    66          0
        Mouse       69    66          25
        CPU         70    66          0
        Stationary  71    57          0
        Pencil      72    71          0
        Ruler       73    71          0
        Mechanical  74    67          30
        Membrane    75    67          0
```

this is how i want my function to return values.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this looks like calculating the transitive closure. If your DBMS supports SQL3, try using `WITH RECURSIVE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server the query will look like:

```
WITH temp (ID, UnderGRoupId, Quantity)
AS
(
    SELECT ID, UnderGRoupId, Quantity
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable cc WHERE cc.UnderGRoupId = MyTable.ID)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT MyTable.ID, MyTable.UnderGRoupId, Quantity + MyTable.Quantity
    FROM MyTable
    INNER JOIN temp ON MyTable.ID = temp.UnderGRoupId
)

SELECT ID, SUM(Quantity) FROM
(SELECT ID, Quantity - (SELECT Amount FROM MyTable M WHERE M.ID = temp.ID) Quantity
FROM temp) X
GROUP BY ID
```